# Is Method swizzling in a static library possible?

Tags: objective-c, logging, automation, click, method-swizzling

I'm trying to create an automatic UI logging and I found method swizzling as a really nice solution to the problem. I've tried to swizzle the `sendAction` method of the `UIApplication` implementation.

My issue is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Especially if I write the code in a static library, export it to an .a file and use it in my project.

1. should method swizzling be a problem if its implemented within a static library?
2. even in code, it sometimes work and sometimes nothing happens. It always go into the `load` method but not always into the `heap_sendAction` method.

Here is the code:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIApplication (EventAutomator)

+ (void)load 
{
    Class class = [self class];
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(sendAction:to:from:forEvent:);
    SEL replacementSelector = @selector(heap_sendAction:to:from:forEvent:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method replacementMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, replacementSelector);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, replacementMethod);
}

- (BOOL)heap_sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target from:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSString *selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(action);
    printf("Selector %s occurred.\n", [selectorName UTF8String]);
    return [self heap_sendAction:action to:target from:sender forEvent:event];
}

@end
```

----- UPDATE ---- :

heap_sendAction is called when i place the function inside a viewcontroller.m class.
I'm trying different code locations now to see when it works and when it doesnt.

Comment: Please, provide more information in which cases `heap_sendAction` called and in which doesn't. Is that totally random? On button tap? When method called explicitly from the code? Other cases?

Comment: updated original message.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple documentation regarding `load` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/):

> The load message is sent to classes and categories that are both
>   dynamically loaded and statically linked, but only if the newly loaded
>   class or category implements a method that can respond.
>
> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. All initializers in any framework you link to.
> 2. All +load methods in your image.
> 3. All C++ static initializers and C/C++ **attribute**(constructor) functions in your image.
> 4. All initializers in frameworks that link to you.
>
> In addition:
>
> - A class’s +load method is called after all of its superclasses’ +load methods.
> - A category +load method is called after the class’s own +load method.

So, method swizzling is not a problem, even in static library, because classes from frameworks you link to already loaded at this point. `method_exchangeImplementations` should work as expected. Looks like problem is somewhere else.

Comment: As i mentioned, the"load" method is properly implemented and always works. my issue is with the second part, that sometimes works and sometimes doesnt... 

I have no clue where to look for the bug. its a very simple code block, is there any clues i should look for?

Maybe the code that's executed in the "load" method is being over written at a certain point?